# SQL IN statement to create exclusion query

Tags: sql

I asked this question last week on SO-

[SQL Exclusion Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6849350/sql-exclusion-query)

It looks like my criteria has changed so I will reask using my current info:

Is it possible in a single SQL statement to do the following:

Use a subset of telephone numbers in an IN statement, for example `IN(8001231000,8001231001,8001231002)`. Then query my database that has phone numbers in it, and return which phone numbers in the original subset of my IN statement are NOT in my database? My db is Oracle 10g.

Basically instead of bringing back which phone numbers ARE `IN(8001231000,8001231001,8001231002)`, I want to know which phone numbers `IN(8001231000,8001231001,8001231002)` are NOT in my database.

I'm thinking I need to create a temporary table kind of like the answer from my previous question:

```
SELECT level - 1 + 8001231000
   FROM dual
CONNECT BY level <= 8001239999-8001231000+1
```

But instead of doing a range of numbers, I need to perform a query that can be built using an IN statement.  The user will be inputting their telephone number list directly into the IN statement instead of selecting a static range of numbers.

How would I build this in a single statement so I could join and exclude my database result from this list so it would only return the telephone numbers NOT found in my database?  Can I do a LEVEL CONNECT BY on a list instead of a range?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will generate a table (replacing &x with your IN statement) that can be queried against.

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT regexp_substr(&x, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) phone_number
           FROM dual
         CONNECT BY LEVEL <= length(&x) - length(REPLACE(&x, ',', '')) + 1)
 WHERE phone_number NOT IN (SELECT phone_table.phone_number 
                              FROM phone_table)
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you can do this using `NOT IN` and putting your values or another table as the operand

Answer (score 1):

I gave [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6849350/sql-exclusion-query/6849419#6849419) to your original question, and it seems even more appropriate if you have an arbitrary list of numbers instead of a range.  Here's my answer:

I would load a temporary table with all the phone numbers you want to check, and do an exclusion join:

```
SELECT a.phone_number
FROM phone_numbers_i_want_to_check AS a
LEFT OUTER JOIN phone_numbers AS b
  ON a.phone_number = b.phone_number
WHERE b.phone_number IS NULL;
```

Comment: I don't have the ability to write to this database.  It needs to be in a single statement.

Comment: But I agree, that would be the ideal thing to do :)

Answer (score 0):

seems to me that you want to have a new table that contains the phone number list you want to compare.

then you can do an IN and a NOT IN query that SELECTs from this table to get the set that matches, and the set that does not match.

trying with hardcoded IN strings will be the same, but more to type - e.g. the NOT IN version will be a duplicate.

Comment: I don't have the ability to write to this database. It needs to be in a single statement.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question, you want to do a SELECT on the array itself (so can't use IN or NOT IN directly).

Not sure what dialect you've got, but here's a TSQL approach:

1. Convert array to table with a Function
2. Select using the function

The function:

```
CREATE Function [dbo].[ParseIntList]  (@intArray nvarchar(4000) )  
Returns @tbl_int Table  (ParsedInteger Int)  As  

BEGIN 

DECLARE @end Int,
        @start Int

SET @intArray =  @intArray + ',' 
SET @start=1
SET @end=1

WHILE @end<Len(@intArray)
    BEGIN
        SET @end = CharIndex(',', @intArray, @end)
        INSERT INTO @tbl_int 
            SELECT
                Cast(Substring(@intArray, @start, @end-@start) As Int)

        SET @start=@end+1
        SET @end = @end+1
    END

RETURN
END
```

The SELECT:

```
Declare @intArray = varchar(max)
SET @intArray= '8001231000,8001231001,8001231002'

SELECT CAST(1 as varchar(1)) + CAST(ParsedInteger as varchar(10)) 
FROM (Select ParsedInteger From dbo.ParseIntList(@intArray)) a 
WHERE ParsedInteger NOT IN (Select PhoneNumber FROM myOtherDatabaseTable)
```